# Referencing a figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


Figure \ref{fig:DA}.
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{DiferentialAmplifier.jpg}
    \caption{Differential op-amp}
    \label{fig:DA}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is what I wrote but while I press quick build, it  shows 'Reference fig:DA on page 1 undefined.' Can anyone help me with the mistake that I am making, please.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For the labels to work you have to compile the document more than once. Did you compile the document again?

Comment: Just been beaten in the edit..., cannot withdraw my edit :-(.

Comment: I do not have any compilation errors ...

Comment: For `\label..\ref`-referencing to work you need to compile the document more than once while ensuring that automatically created auxiliary-files are **not** deleted between compilation-runs.